# Regex issue in C# for constructing new pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regular expression

```
string expression = "q(\\d+)(M){0,1}(T){0,1}(W){0,1}(TH){0,1}(F){0,1}(S){0,1}(SU){0,1}";
```

Consider days of week.

```
M, T, W, TH, F, S, SUN
```

Whenever we enter any string we want to extract first pattern of days of week and ignore the other one.

Let me give you examples

1. If Input string is : `q10MTWTHFSSUN465689213MTWSU45454`, then output should be  `q10MTWTHFSSUN`
2. Input string = `q10MSSUN454545asdasdsaMTWTHUR`
   Output should be `q10MSSUN`

CODE

```
    string expression = "q(\\d+)(M){0,1}(T){0,1}(W){0,1}(TH){0,1}(F){0,1}(S){0,1}(SU){0,1}";
    Console.Write("\nEnter string:");
    string value = Console.ReadLine();
    var result = Regex.Match(value, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (result != null)
    {
        Console.Write(result.ToString());
    }
```

I tried the above pattern, but failing in some scenerios.

**FAILING SCENARIO**

Input string `q10THSSUN454545asd`

Output should be `q10THSSUN` but it is coming out as `q10T` because it is treating `TH` as `Tuesday` because of `T`

Comment: "but failing in some scenerios" isn't enough information. *Which* scenarios? You clearly have more information here, so please specify it. (A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be more helpful than snippets...)

Comment: Also, the examples are incorrect. Your regex says 'TH', your days of the week says 'THU', and your expected result says 'THUR'

Comment: why don't you replace `{0,1}` to `?`  (+_+)...
and `(SU)` should be `(SUN)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`q(\\d+)(M){0,1}(T(?!H)){0,1}(W){0,1}(TH){0,1}(F){0,1}(S(?!U)){0,1}(SU){0,1}`

The regex for matching 'T' (Tuesday) explicitly fails if the following letter is a 'H' (so that TH takes precedence). Same goes with Saturday and Sunday.

You could also replace the `{0,1}` with `?` for brevity, but it's just a matter of preference, really.